# Get woocommerce product price on php page

Tags: php, wordpress, get, woocommerce, price

I've tried it a long long time to get the price from a specific product on a php file but I cant find a solution. I've tried it with woocommerce shortcodes but I always get the full product in my div and not the price.

Does anybody know a solution?

Thank you so much!

```html
<div class="package-header">
    <span class="packe-title bronze-title">Bronze</span>
</div>
<div class="price-container">
    <?php $price=get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_regular_price'); echo $price; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a product object. Then you can use any of WooCommerce's product class methods, such as `get_price_html()`

```
$product_id = 99;
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
echo $product->get_price_html();
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!